# Changes made in one tableviewcell effect other cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

My problem is, that I have a tableview with a number of cells. Inside of those cells there are images, that get a green border if they are being taped. If I have a lot of cells and I tap for example the first pic in the first cell, that's when the problem happens. When I start scrolling down the table a little faster, other cells of the same type also have the first picture with green border, even though they are in cell number 13 or something. I think that's because they are reusable cells, but how can I make sure, that only the one cell that is being taped, keeps the change? Hope you guys got what I meant, I know it's kinda confusing. Here is one of the two custom cells, with the code that turns the border green. The images of type bouncingRoundImages, are just UIImages, I created the custom subclass of UIImage to make them bounce.

```
class TwoPicsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var firstImage: bouncingRoundImageView!
@IBOutlet var secondImage: bouncingRoundImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    containerView.clipsToBounds = true

    setupFirstImage()
    setupSecondImage()
}


func setupFirstImage() {

    let tappedOne = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(checkPicTwo))
    firstImage.addGestureRecognizer(tappedOne)
}

func setupSecondImage() {
    let tappedTwo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(checkPicOne))
    secondImage.addGestureRecognizer(tappedTwo)
}

func checkPicTwo() {

    firstImage.bouncing()

    if secondImage.layer.borderWidth != 0 {
        secondImage.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
}

func checkPicOne() {

    secondImage.bouncing()

    if firstImage.layer.borderWidth != 0 {
        firstImage.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Update your question with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and any other code in your table view controller that updates cells of your table view.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a reusable cell problem. Try setting the image to nil and borderWidth to 0 in prepareForReuse.

```
override func prepareForReuse()
{
    super.prepareForReuse()
    firstImage.image = nil
    secondImage.image = nil
    firstImage.layer.borderWidth = 0
    secondImage.layer.borderWidth = 0
}
```

Comment: this kinda works :D it solves the problem that the cells, that were not tapped, don't have the border, but when I scroll back up, the originally tapped cell also doesn't have the border color anymore. Is there a good way to handle that?

Comment: You need to have a property that states if it's selected or not. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can check this property to give it a border or not.

Comment: ok I'll try to figure out how to do that. Would be great if you can provide some sample code Morten Stulen! Thanks already for your help